# new tab in page product view frontend?

Tags: tabs

I need to set a new tab in my page product view in frontend for only my CUSTOM type of product, i have tried:
copy the catalog.xml from /theme/layout and paste in my theme/layout, and inserted my custom product:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Virtual)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Incomm Virtual)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_virtual" name="product.info.virtual" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.virtual.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual>
```

and calls in my another catalog.xml in subfolder from layout, with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="incomm_termos" as="termos" template="fourward/incomm/product/view/termos.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Terms of Use</value></action>
        </block>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual>
</layout>
```

but nothing happens, i need to create a new tab after description product and i prefer to make in code and only for my custom type of product. how i have to do? 
i have follows the http://twincreations.co.uk/add-custom-product-tab-in-magento-1-9-ce/ but i dont know how to use in multiples ways (filtered for type of product). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `<reference name="product.info">` in your layout.  So your block is added in the page but it not associated to the tabs section.

Try it like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual translate="label" module="catalog">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="incomm_termos" as="termos" template="fourward/incomm/product/view/termos.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
               <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Terms of Use</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual>
</layout>
```

Comment: `<PRODUCT_TYPE_incomm_virtual \translate="label" module="catalog">` \(slash) will not work in xml :(

Comment: @liyakat. Sorry. I have big fingers. It was a typo :)

Comment: Marius.. Don't be..You are always Perfect.+1 for me.